# Library Linking Issue? MinGW OpenCV Doesn't Output Anything

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, mingw

I have been trying to compile a basic OpenCV example with MinGW g++. It compiles however when I run main.exe there is no output. My guess is that I have a library linking issue, and I haven't linked any `lib` folder at any point nor added it to path. I've been at this for 8+ days and I really appreciate the help.

**Build**

- MinGW-W64 8.1.0 x86_x64-posix-seh-rev0
- Windows 10
- OpenCV 4.5.2 minGW prebuilt binaries from [this git repo](https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build)
- I also tried building from source with cmake. `std::cout << image.size` does work, but `cv::imshow()` fails

**Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "do something" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("../resources/corrected_10_0.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    assert(!image.empty());
    std::cout << image.size;
    // cv::namedWindow("test", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // cv::imshow("test", image);
    // cv::waitKey(0);
    // cv::destroyWindow("test");
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation**

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main -IC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\include \
-LC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\bin -llibopencv_core452 \
-llibopencv_highgui452 -llibopencv_imgcodecs452
```

**Windows Path Variable**
Points to my MinGW binaries and the OpenCV mingW install bin folder/

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin
C:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\bin
```

** **EDIT** **
I have not installed any 3rd party libraries/dependencies like zlib or libjpeg. Do I need to download those and then link to them?

Comment: `-lopencv_core452` (w/o `lib`prefix) etc.

Comment: @berak Just tried `g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main -IC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\include -LC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\bin -lopencv_core452 -lopencv_highgui452 -lopencv_imgcodecs452; ./main` and it didn't work (although no errors were thrown). Being said I didn't realize `-l` searched for `lib*`.

Comment: make it `-LC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\lib`  (and g++ is notoriously bad at telling you it did not find libs ...)

Comment: @berak that didn't work either. I also tried it with `[opencvfile...]\bin` removed from path and also with it replaced with `...\lib`. Also I checked the cmake configuration, and its built to use dynamically linked libraries. `\lib` contains `.dll.a` static files while `\bin\` contains `.dll`  dynamically linked files

Comment: 1. g++ needs the `lib`folder containing your `dll.a` libs,  2.  the `.dll` binaries folder (`bin`) goes on the PATH (confusing, but 2 very seperate things)

Comment: @berak still doesn't work. I kept `C:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\bin` in PATH and ran `g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main -IC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\include -LC:\Libs\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\x64\mingw\lib -lopencv_core452 -lopencv_highgui452 -lopencv_imgcodecs452`

Comment: @berak Thanks for the help, I got it to work! (but I'm not completely sure why).